# Create jsp page with html to pdf

Tags: mysql, jsp, html-parsing, pdfptable

I am doing a jsp project where the user adds questions(say he has added 20 questions)using tinymce and this questions are sent to the mysql database.Next this questions need to be printed on a pdf directly from the database.
I have already done most of it.Using htmlworker.parse I have passed the questions to pdf,but the only problem here is that the questions come in a single column.I tried to use pdfptable but I cant use,so that I can sort these questions into tables or 2 columns.Could anyone suggest me some way.